# Inotify compatible Shell script to monitor shell a certain directory

Tags: linux, shell, monitor, inotify

This is first question in Stack overflow.  need an inotify compatible script writing that will monitor a certain directory, and if any new files/folders are created in in, copy those files to another folder. I need the script to monitor constantly for changes rather than run periodically.
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `inotifywait`, from the `inotify-tools` page, to build something like this.  A typical use:

```
inotifywait -m /tmp | while read path events name; do
  echo "Now I am going to do something with $name in directory $path."
done
```

There are oodles of options for controlling how `inotifywait` operates; consult the man page for details.

Comment: Thank you..Can you tell me the logic on how to do the task I asked. Also, can u suggest me some good tutorials on inotify.